# Telerik Reporting Table Set Textbox Value From Code

Tags: c#, textbox, telerik, report, telerik-reporting

I am using telerik report and I have a table. The textbox16 has the value I need to use on my query to set the value on textbox26. Each line has different value on textbox16 (unique ) .

The problem is that on textbox26 I am getting the wrong values for all the rows!

When I debug my program in textbox26_itemdatabound puts the correct values.

What I am doing wrong and how I can fix it?

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stockConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        private void textBox26_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           decimal balance = 0, debit = 0;

            Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox textBox = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox)sender;

            string text = textBox.Text;
            textBox26.Value = text;

            string querty = "SELECT Sum(st.Debit),comp.balance  FROM statemnt st left join companie comp on st.accountcode=comp.code and comp.type=1 " +
                           "where   st.accountcode=@compcode and (Date(st.DocDate)>=(CURDATE() - interval 30 day)) ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(querty, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compcode", text);
            con.Open();

            MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (!Reader.HasRows)
            {
                return;
            }
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    debit = Convert.ToDecimal(Reader.GetString(0));
                }
                catch { debit = 0; }
                try
                {
                    balance = Convert.ToDecimal(Reader.GetString(1));
                    this.textBox26.Value = balance.ToString("#.##");
                }
                catch
                {
                    balance = 0;
                }
            }
            Reader.Close();
            con.Close();


            if (balance <= 0)
            {
                this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (debit < balance)
                {
                    balance = balance - debit;
                    this.textBox26.Value = debit.ToString("#.##");
                }
            }

        }



        private void textBox16_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox26.Value = textBox16.Value;
        }
```

The result:

[image: Results]

Comment: Is the textBox.text a user input? Why to you assign 5 times consecutively the value 0.00 to textBox26?

Comment: The textbox.text is not a user input.The 5 times there you see is for for 5 columns that i will creater textbox26-31 after i manage to do this with the value.. on the textbox26 i want to put the value that i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with the code below! I remove it from textBox26_ItemDataBound and added my code to textBox16_ItemDataBound  and it is working perfect!

```
 private void textBox16_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                decimal balance = 0, debit = 0;



            Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox txt = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.TextBox)sender;

            string text = txt.ToString();

            //SPLIT WARD (textBox26) TextBox[Text=-99]
            string s = text;
            string[] words = s.Split('=');
            text = words[1];
            words = text.Split(']');
            text = words[0];


            string querty = "SELECT Sum(st.Debit),comp.balance  FROM companie comp left join  statemnt st on st.accountcode=comp.code and st.AccountType='DB' and comp.type=1 and (Date(st.DocDate)>=(CURDATE() - interval 30 day))" +
                            "where   comp.code=@compcode ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(querty, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compcode", text);
            con.Open();

            MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (!Reader.HasRows)
            {
                return;
            }
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    debit = Convert.ToDecimal(Reader.GetString(0));
                }
                catch { debit = 0; }
                try
                {
                    balance = Convert.ToDecimal(Reader.GetString(1));
                    this.textBox6.Value = balance.ToString("n2");
                }
                catch
                {
                    balance = 0;
                }
            }
            Reader.Close();



            if (balance <= 0)
            {
                this.textBox7.Value = "0.00";
                this.textBox15.Value = "0.00";
                this.textBox13.Value = "0.00";
                this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                //textbox6
                con.Close();
                return;

            }
            else
            {
                if (debit < balance)
                {
                    balance = balance - debit;
                    if (debit == 0)
                    {
                        this.textBox7.Value = "0.00";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.textBox7.Value = debit.ToString("n2");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textBox7.Value = balance.ToString("n2");
                    this.textBox15.Value = "0.00";
                    this.textBox13.Value = "0.00";
                    this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                    con.Close();
                    return;
                }
                querty = " SELECT Sum(st.Debit) FROM companie comp left join  statemnt st  on st.accountcode=comp.code and st.AccountType='DB' and comp.type=1 and Date(st.DocDate)<=(CURDATE() - interval 31 day) and (Date(st.DocDate)>=(CURDATE() - interval 60 day))  " +
                                 "where   comp.code=@compcode ";

                cmd = new MySqlCommand(querty, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compcode", text);
                try
                {//string x=cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                debit = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                catch { debit = 0; }

                if (debit < balance)
                {
                    this.textBox15.Value = debit.ToString("n2");
                    balance = balance - debit;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textBox15.Value = balance.ToString("n2");
                    this.textBox13.Value = "0.00";
                    this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                    con.Close();
                    return;

                }
                querty = " SELECT Sum(st.Debit) FROM companie comp left join  statemnt st on st.accountcode=comp.code and st.AccountType='DB' and comp.type=1 and Date(st.DocDate)<=(CURDATE() - interval 61 day) and (Date(st.DocDate)>=(CURDATE() - interval 90 day))" +
                               "where   comp.code=@compcode   ";

                cmd = new MySqlCommand(querty, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compcode", text);

                try
                {
                    debit = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                catch
                {
                    debit = 0; 
                }
                if (debit < balance)
                {
                    this.textBox13.Value = debit.ToString("n2");
                    balance = balance - debit;
                    this.textBox26.Value = balance.ToString("n2");
                    con.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    this.textBox13.Value = balance.ToString("n2");
                    this.textBox26.Value = "0.00";
                    con.Close();
                    return;
                }




            }
```